# Как вывести из запроса по условию со значениями по умолчанию?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица (тип, валюта, клиент, процент):

```
+-------+----------+----------+------+
| type  | currency | cust_id  | rate |
+-------+----------+----------+------+
| R1    | all      | all      |    1 |
| R1    | USD      | all      |    1 |
| R1    | GPB      | all      |    5 |
| R1    | ALL      | 15       |    3 |
| R2    | USD      | 15       |    5 |
| R2    | ALL      | 15       |    7 |
| R2    | EUR      | 15       |   10 |
+-------+----------+----------+------+
```

Для запроса ввод это (тип, валюта, клиент), а вывод - процент.

Если был задан не существующий клиент или валюта, то это относится к ALL.

Нужен скрипт, который при вводе типа валюты и клиента выдаст мне процент, а если нет значений для валюты или клиента, то по умолчанию искать для ALL.

Comment: похоже вы забыли задать вопрос...

Comment: мне нужен скрипт который при вводе типа валюты и клиента выдаст мне процент, и если нету той валюты или клиента то он относится к ALL

Comment: тогда отберите все подходящие записи (Т.е. видимо по требуемому клиенту и все all заодно) и отсортируйте полученную выборку по клиенту и валюте. первая запись и будет требуемой

Answer (score 2):

Следующий запрос вернёт ожидаемый результат:

```sql
select 
    t.type, t.cust_id, t.currency, t.rate 
from (select t.*, 
    case currency when 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end currno,  
    case cust_id  when 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end custno from t  
) t, (select 'R1' ty, 15 cu, 'RUB' cr from dual) args
where type=args.ty 
and cust_id in (args.cu,'ALL') and currency in (args.cr,'ALL')
order by custno, currno 
fetch first row only
/
TY CUS CUR       RATE
-- --- --- ----------
R1 15  ALL          3
```

---

Тестовые данные:

```
create table t as 
with data (
        type, currency, cust_id, rate) as (
select 'R1', 'ALL',     'ALL',      1 from dual union all
select 'R1', 'USD',     'ALL',      1 from dual union all
select 'R1', 'GPB',     'ALL',      5 from dual union all
select 'R1', 'ALL',     '15',       3 from dual union all
select 'R2', 'USD',     '15',       5 from dual union all
select 'R2', 'ALL',     '15',       7 from dual union all
select 'R2', 'EUR',     '15',      10 from dual
) select * from data
```